# How to constantly update intensity graph in LabVIEW?

Tags: labview

I'm working on a LabVIEW project that receives a long string via USB port from a microcontroller, tokenizes it into smaller data and stores them in an 8×8 2D-array. My aim is to visually present these data using an intensity graph of the same size (8×8).

The most elegant way to provide the user a feedback of local intensities would be a graph that updates smoothly, i.e. it is not blinking, the graph is not being cleared after showing all 64 intensity data, and so on.

I've been wondering if there exists some sort of setting for intensity graphs to update the data more smoothly, something like the Update mode in the case of Waveform charts.

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an notifier, in the sub-vi you write your 8x8 array into the notifier.
In the main/GUI VI you have a seperate while loop that waits on notifier updates. When the notifier is fired you:

1. Defer panel updates
2. Copy the data from the notifier into the intensity graph
3. Undefer panel updates

The reason for the notifier over a queue or user events is that it can only have one dataset (the latest).

Answer (score 2):

You could use that option about smooth.
[image]

Here that's the program.
[image]

Drag this picture to your Desktop, after that drag picture from your desktop to your LabVIEW. The LabVIEW program will appear in your block diagram like magic.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I managed to solve it. I realised I've placed the buffer array inside a subVI instead of the main one, although the plotting happens in the main VI. This seemed to cause quite a large delay as the subVI (that is responsible for tokenizing the input stream) is running for a relatively long time, making the transitions of the intensity graph quite lagging.